# Should I be worrying about limiting the number of textures in my game?

Tags: xna, gui, assets

I am working on a GUI in XNA 4.0 at the moment. (Before you point out that there are many GUIs already in existance, this is as much a learning exercise as a practical project). As you may know, controls and dialogs in Windows actually consist of a number of system-level windows. For instance, a dialog box may consist of a window for the whole dialog, a child window for the client area, another window (barely showing) for the frame, and so on. This makes detecting mouse hits and doing clipping relatively easy. I'd like to design my XNA GUI along the same lines, but using overlapping Textures instead of windows obviously.

My question (yes, there's actually a question in this drivel) is: am I at risk of adversely affecting game performance and/or running low in resources if I get too nuts with the creating of many small textures? I haven't been able to find much information on how resource-tight the XNA environment actually is. I grew up in the days of 64K ram so I'm used to obsessing about resources and optimization.

Anyway, any feedback appreciated.

Comment: This is where the obligatory Michael A. Jackson quote comes in: "The First Rule of Program Optimization: Don't do it. The Second Rule of Program Optimization (for experts only!): Don't do it yet." It is usually more important for your program to be understandable, and maintain structure, than to perform optimizations. PC Video cards today are extremely powerful, and even with thousands of state changes per frame, they will hardly break a sweat. However, if this is an optimization learning exercise, or you're programming embedded devices, then it's a whole different story.

Answer (score 3):

Any slowness in this situation would be caused by the switching of texture states, as another poster also mentioned.

If you are finding that you have performance problems you can combine all of your small textures into a larger sprite sheet texture to eliminate the switching of which texture is on the GPU. You will just need to use a rect to access the correct portion of the sprite sheet when you make the call to ContentManager.Load().

Comment: +1 for the sprite sheet.  This is definitely the way to go with many small textures.

Comment: Notice the technical term is not "sprite sheet" but "texture atlas". May help you find resources when searching online if you use the most accurate term

Answer (score 1):

Well no, generally not. Only thing is that changing the texture state is somewhat slow. So using less textures can make the rendering of the GUI a whole lot faster (~a few milliseconds). But it won't impact anything outside of the GUI rendering code. We are talking about really tiny amounts of memory here and also tiny amount of indices. That wouldn't even have made a impact 10 years ago.

Comment: BY "changing the texture state" you mean changing the contents of a texture? I get that that probably means cpu time, then reloading the texture into the gpu area. But what about for instance moving textures around on the display. Does that load the cpu or is that mostly gpu? See, these are the types of questions that can be important for writing code but are generally only answered through experience -- either your own or that of people who've already tried it.

Comment: Textures most definitely do not take up "tiny amounts of memory".

Comment: @Donutz No, I meant switching between textures. Drawing two rectangles with the same texture is much faster than drawing two rectangles with different textures. It's all done on the GPU, no texture data is loaded from the GPU to the CPU (unless you explicitly ask for it). The CPU is doing nothing but sending orders/data to the GPU, from which the GPU then builds the picture and sends it to the monitor.

Comment: @ktodisco Context. The OP specially asked for "small" textures.

Comment: @Mr.Beast, thanks for that. I know in computer science we're taught that the computer should be programmed as an abstract machine and hardware specifics shouldn't be important. But for cases like XNA and video programming, a detailed discussion of what happens behind the scenes would really help for understanding how programming strategies actually play out.

Comment: "*Textures most definitely do not take up "tiny amounts of memory"*" - depends on the size of the texture.  The OP mentioned "many small textures", and even a 256x256 unmipped texture is only 256k, which - considering that 1gb of video RAM is entry level nowadays - is quite frankly miniscule.  It's not 1996 any more.

Comment: @mh01 Regardless of the size of the textures, they will still be the most dense assets in the game in terms of memory.  Implying that they occupy minuscule amounts of memory is wrong.  Fitting textures into available memory is still a problem today.  On a small game it will not be a problem, but it's crucial to know that it can be.

Comment: Actually, even though changing the texture state (or any other render state) has a very small penalty, what actually hits performance really hard is not the state change, but uploading the texture to vRAM. If all your textures fit (and stay) in vRAM, changing the render state is almost unnoticeable (at least compared to the cost of uploading a new texture)

Comment: "*Regardless of the size of the textures, they will still be the most dense assets in the game in terms of memory*" - that would be true if the OP were writing a game.  But this isn't about a game; it's about a GUI.  Let's try to keep things on-topic and with reference to the question being asked, eh?

Comment: The XNA GUI is obviously for a game.

Answer (score 0):

> I'd like to design my XNA GUI along the same lines, but using
>   overlapping Textures instead of windows

This is a bit of a tangent on your actual question, but bear with me.

I may be taking your wording a bit too literally but in the event I am not, I would suggest that you do not represent your GUI elements with a series of `Texture2D` instances, but rather, a collection of `Rectangle` instances.  You could then wrap the `Rectangle` with something such as `BaseWindow` class, where each base window class holds both a rectangle and a texture, as well as other tidbits that you will need to manage the object.  This will allow you to have windows that are not the same size as your texture, so that you can employ a few tricks (such as a 1x1 pixel texture being stretched to entirety of the window to simply fill with a solid color).

Now on to your real question.

> am I at risk of adversely affecting game performance and/or running
>   low in resources if I get too nuts with the creating of many small
>   textures?

If you are loading up all of your textures via the `ContentManager`, then your chances of adversely affecting performance is minimal.  The reason being that the content manager class handles duplicate texture loading for you, by simply returning a reference to the original loaded texture, should you try to load the same texture all over again.  This makes it very easy for you, since you really don't have to worry about managing duplicate resources.

However, common sense and good programming practice still applies.